# Join последних записей из таблицы (hasMany)

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы, в одной хранятся сущности, а во второй их версионность. Как выбрать последние версии для этих сущностей?

Чтоб на выходе получить

```
| account_actual_id | account_id |  name  | added_date |
|______________________________________________________|
| 3                 | 2          |'First' | 2016-11-03 |
|______________________________________________________|
| 4                 | 5          |'Second'| 2016-11-03 |
```

Структура для тестов.

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
    `account_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `account_actual` (
    `account_actual_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `account_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `added_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`account_actual_id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `u` (`account_id`, `added_date`),
    INDEX `added_date` (`added_date`),
    INDEX `account_id` (`account_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk__account_actual_account` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `account` (`account_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `account` VALUES (2, 'First');
INSERT INTO `account` VALUES (3, 'Second');

INSERT INTO `account_actual` VALUES (1, 2, '2016-11-01');
INSERT INTO `account_actual` VALUES (2, 3, '2016-11-01');
INSERT INTO `account_actual` VALUES (3, 2, '2016-11-03');
INSERT INTO `account_actual` VALUES (4, 3, '2016-11-03');
INSERT INTO `account_actual` VALUES (5, 2, '2016-11-02');
INSERT INTO `account_actual` VALUES (6, 3, '2016-11-02');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/933f9c/1

Продуктивность крайне важна. Таблицы миллионики

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой вариант

```
select a.*, b.*
  from account a
  join account_actual b on b.account_id = a.account_id
  left join account_actual c on c.account_id = b.account_id and b.added_date < c.added_date
 where c.account_actual_id is null
```

Для каждой b выбирает все c, которые добавлены позднее. Понятно, что если c нет, то b и есть последняя версия.

Если добавить в account_actual поле prev_id, которое указывает на предыдущую версию, то будет гораздо лучше

```
select a.*, b.*
  from account a
  join account_actual b on b.account_id = a.account_id
  left join account_actual c on c.prev_id = b.actual_account_id
 where c.account_actual_id is null
```

Если нет такой c, которая ссылается на b как на предыдущую версию, то b - последняя версия.
Тут в отличии от предыдущего варианта для каждого b отбирается максимум одна запись c.

Ну и конечно можете искать максимальную added_date

```
select a.*, b.*
  from account a
  join account_actual b on b.account_id = a.account_id
 where b.added_date = (select max(added_date) 
    from account_actual c 
   where c.account_id = b.account_id)
```

Или

```
select a.*, b.*
  from account a
  join account_actual b on b.account_id = a.account_id
 where b.account_actual_id = (select account_actual_id 
    from account_actual c 
   where c.account_id = b.account_id 
   order by added_date limit 1)
```

А если в account хранить id последней версии, то будет вообще здорово. Это тривиальный случай.

Не стесняйтесь добавлять информацию, которая поможет уменьшить объём выборки, увеличив тем самым скорость выполнения запроса.

Уже два дополнения описал, могу предложить и третье. Можно добавить в actual_accaount поле, например deprecated_date, у последней записи оно устанавливается в NULL или очень большую дату, до которой всё равно никто не доживёт. У старой версии оно устанавливается равным added_date следующей версии.

```
select a.*, b.*
  from account a
  join account_actual b on b.account_id = a.account_id and b.deprecated_date IS NULL
```

Comment: Спасибо. 
Хотя 4-й вариант не совсем правильно работает)

Менять структуры базы увы нельзя. ReadOnly. 

Воспользуюсь вариантом 1 или 3, посмотрим на практике который будет быстрей работать.

Answer (score 0):

Тогда будет 2 join:

```
    select account_actual_id, t.*, name from
    (select account_id, max(added_date) added_date
    from `account_actual` group by 1) t join `account` using(account_id)
join `account_actual` aa on aa.account_id=t.account_id AND aa.added_date=t.added_date;
```

другие способы описаны в этой [статье](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/18.html)

Comment: За статью спасибо. За **account_actual_id**, нет)

Comment: Последняя версия это больший account_actual_id или added_date?

Comment: Нужно отталкиваться от **added_date**

Comment: тогда 2 join, обновил ответ

Comment: кстати, у вас избыточный индекс INDEX `account_id` (`account_id`),

Comment: учитывая, что таблица innodb, то потестируйте, возможно будет работать с одним join (но это хак )

Answer (score 0):

> Продуктивность крайне важна. Таблицы миллионики

В этом случае стоило просто забыть о привычной парадигме и попробовать найти решение, отталкиваясь от задачи.

Максимальной производительности вы достигнете в следующем случае:

- Есть одна таблица для хранения версий, первичный ключ - идентификатор сущности и версия сущности
- Есть вторая таблица, в которой хранятся только актуальные версии, абсолютно идентичная за исключением того, что в первичный ключ состоит только из идентификатора сущности

После этого достаточно использовать первую таблицу для аналитики/аудита, а все производительные выборки пускать по второй таблице. При этом не участвуют ни джойны, ни что-то еще, поэтому вряд ли можно придумать что-то производительней; вместо оптимизации запросов можно просто оптимизировать сам алгоритм хранения.

Comment: Согласен, я описал только вершину айсберга. На практике пользователь может еще выбирать срезы. Например за последние три дня. Или рейндж посередине вообще. Так что без **added_date** в  условии не обойтись скорей всего

Comment: @Ninazu все равно помещается в одну таблицу